# PHP & Mongo in Vagrant, " Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'size of BSON doc is x bytes, max is 0' "

Tags: php, mongodb, vagrant

I've a Vagrant setup with Mongo and PHP within, but any time I try to run a simple insert into a Mongo collection, I get the above error,

```
Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'size of BSON doc is 210 bytes, max is 0'
```

The actual code is

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$mongo->newdb->drop();
$db = $mongo->newdb;
$collection = $db->newcollection;
$collection->insert(array ( "_id" => new MongoId("4ec1019f87484465ae4d777e"), "id" => 1));
```

There's nearly no info about this error online, and near all my Vagrant setup is what's stated online to work.  Anybody with an idea why it fails?

Comment: I wonder couldn't the reason be that MongoId is set explicitly in that insert, but its bytes 4-6 (which are, by [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoid.php), a hash of the client's machine hostname) are somehow made invalid with Vagrant setup? Does the insert work without '_id' set?

Comment: @raina77ow, just changed it to 
    $collection->insert(array ("asdf" => 1));
and that didn't work either, thanks for the effort / answer though :)

Comment: Ok, but does querying this empty `newcollection` work?

Comment: Yup, "var_dump($collection->find())" prints "class MongoCursor#5 (0) {
}".

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Vagrant as in the [tool for managing virtualized hosting environments](http://vagrantup.com/), this detail is far less relevant than the actual version of Linux, MongoDB, and the Mongo PHP driver that you're using.  Can you add some information on versions used?

Comment: @Stennie, yeah sorry about that, I thought the answer might be down to a simple Mongo misconfiguration, but the versions of all the stuff, as you said, was what was wrong.  All working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, this was down to a *very* old version of Mongo I had installed, something like 1.4, because of a Vagrant misconfiguration.  Once I sorted that out and installed the most recent one (MongoDB shell version: 2.0.7), everything worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I still get this error, i upgraded the version to the newest one, and it didn't solve the issue, anyone can advice?